# C++ passing 2D array to function only loads one char

Tags: c++

I have a program I am working on that is basically like this:

```
 bool isUnique(char**,int,char[]);

 int main() {
    char** uniqueWords = new char *[MAXWORDSIZE];
    uniqueWords[posofUnique] = new char[MAXWORDSIZE];
    //assign value to uniqueWords[0]="value"
    isUnique(uniqueWords,posofUnique,currentWord);
 }

 bool  isUnique(char **uniqueArray, int amountofArrayFilled, char currentWord[]){
    for (int count =0; count < amountArrayFilled; count++){
        bool isEqual = strcmp(uniqueArray[count],currentWord);
    }
    return false;
}
```

however `uniqueArray` only loads in one character on `strcmp`.  How do I get it to load the entire array?

Comment: I'm assuming isUnique(isUnique( is a typo so I edited your question

Comment: "... only loads in one character on strcmp ..." - what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @AndreyT I mean when I am comparing uniqueArray[count] only appears to have one character such as 'c'

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all. You initialize only the `uniqueWords[posofUnique]` entry, but your cycle inside `isUnique` inspect only entries from `0` to `posofUnique - 1`, i.e. only the non-initialized entries. How is that supposed to work and what is the point of this?

Comment: @Travis - If the assignment didn't specify the method declarations to implement, use **std::string** and **std::vector<std::string>**. That eases your job a lot and makes code look a bit easy to understand :)

Comment: @Mahesh wish I could but assignment says C-String

Comment: @AndreyT...trying to keep as much of my code out of here as possible due to University restrictions.  But, it does have a loop which initializes it like 

     `uniqueWords[posofUnique] = new char [MAXWORDSIZE];
     uniqueWords[posofUnique] = currentWord;`

Comment: @Travis Pessetto: Well, you'll have to post more of it. What you posted so far just makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `uniqueWords` array has `MAXWORDSIZE` elements and all of them contain garbage pointer values immediately after allocation.

Then you set `uniqueWords[posofUnique]` pointer to some newly allocated memory. So, that single entry now holds some more-or-less meaningful value. The other entries of `uniqueWords` array still contain garbage values.

Then you call `isUnique`, which attempts to inspect array entries from `uniqueWords[0]` to `uniqueWords[posofUnique - 1]`. But these entries still contain meaningless garbage values!

So, whatever you see through these non-initialized entries means absolutely noting. It is just some unpredictable garbage at some random address in memory. You say you see "only one character" there? Congratulations. With the same degree of success you can discover the lost proof of Fermat's Great Theorem there.

Comment: I'm surprised it didn't segfault.

Comment: Would it help if I said the first character was the correct one from a word loaded in from a file?

Comment: @Travis Pessetto: A typical `char` can hold only 256 different values. If the rest of the characters were wrong, then the fact that the first one was correct could be a mere coincidence. It doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

look at the documentation for strcmp.
Either you are giving garbage data for uniqueArray, or currentWord.
If you have a debugger, step through the code to make sure the values are correct.